# I need to submit the form and redirect the parent page on form submission in a fancy box

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, fancybox

This is the form code given in the fancybox popup iframe page.

I need to close this popup and redirect the parent page to the

http://luxuryresortstayvouchers.com/newdesign/?p=list.php

when the submit button is pressed.

following function is effectively closing the fancybox popup but the parent page is not redirected to the desired location.

```
function closeMeUp()
{
parent.$.fancybox.close();
}




    <form action=""http://luxuryresortstayvouchers.com/newdesign/?p=list.php method="post" target="_parent" class="form_class" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

        <input class="vouch_num" type="text"  placeholder="Checkin date" maxlength="25" size="50" id="datepicker" />
        <input class="vouch_num" type="text"  placeholder="Checkout date" maxlength="25" size="50" id="datepicker2" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="ok" class="submit_but" value="Submit" onClick="closeMeUp();" />
        <input type="button" id="cancel" class="cancel_but" value="Cancel" />

    </form>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your input is of type "button". Shouldn't it be "submit"?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `parent.window.location.href` property inside the `onsubmit` attribute of your (iframed) `form` like :

```
<form id="login_form"
onsubmit="javascript:parent.window.location.href='http://luxuryresortstayvouchers.com/newdesign/?p=list.php';" > 

...
</form>
```

**Notice** that you don't have to force closing fancyBox since the page redirection will do the job.

Also **notice** that if you close fancyBox manually (without submitting the form), the parent page won't be redirected.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2aZ7U/show/)**